# Unable to fix Hugo architecture when hosted on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, http-status-code-404, structure, hosting, hugo

I am new to Hugo and tried to create a hugo website using [hugo's tutorial](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/) and then putting it online with a predefined theme named [simplicity](https://themes.gohugo.io/simplicity/) using their [gitlab tutorial](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-gitlab/).

However my website seems to be missing the theme for the index page and the structure seems to be missing.
You can find [the gitlab repo here](https://gitlab.com/guillaume_slizewicz/guillaumeslizewicz/) and the [index page here](https://guillaume_slizewicz.gitlab.io/guillaumeslizewicz/).

For instance, the posts link does not link to https://username.gitlab.io/website/posts but to https://username.gitlab.io/posts .

The website works well locally and I am not sure how to fix the structure on gitlab. I have tried tweaking the .gitlab-ci.yml and config.toml documents to no avail.
Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: You might want to fork from the GitLab Pages Hugo example project: https://gitlab.com/pages/hugo If you spent too much time already on your site and have the feeling that you are only missing a detail, you could still look at the example and try to find out what configuration is different.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKainrad I think I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually fixed the problem with help from [hugo's discourse community](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/hugo-architecture-not-working-when-hosted-on-gitlab/16847/6) by changing the baseurl, rebuilding the website, and paying attention to cache/ trying with another browser.